# Check if a time and date range satisfies a cron expression

Tags: java, spring, cron

Wondering how can I check if a date/time range satisfies a cron expression in Java. For example, if I say I have time range from

> Monday 12:00 AM to 7:00 AM

and mention cron `0 0 6 * * MON`, the comparison should give me true.

Comment: where you put the cron ?

Comment: Let us say I have a method with parameters start time, end time and the cron expression, this method should tell me if the there was at least one instance when cron would have triggered in that time period.

Comment: So you want a cron expression evaluator in Java?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of others too, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2362985/642706), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5973797/642706), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46344453/642706), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4363952/642706). Please search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting. And explain how your Question is not addressed by past ones.

Comment: @BasilBourque Actually I was looking for a method which takes in start and end timestamp and a cron expression. Then it checks for how many times during this window the cron would have triggered. As of now, I cannot answer this question as this is marked duplicate so I am putting the logic in comments.

Comment: public int compareCronWithDateRange(String cronExpn, Timestamp t1, Timestamp t2) {
  int counter = 0;
  if(cronExpn != null && !cronExpn.isEmpty()){
   CronSequenceGenerator cronSeqGen = new CronSequenceGenerator(cronExpn);
   Date incrementalDate = t1;
   while(t2.after(incrementalDate)){
    incrementalDate = cronSeqGen.next(incrementalDate);
    if(incrementalDate.before(t2)){
     counter++;
    }
   }
  }
  return counter;
 }

Comment: @BasilBourque - If this was a duplicate ask please let me know. I feel other question are asking something different.

Comment: @BasilBourque - If you think this is not duplicate, please unmark it. Thanks!